# send from variable in #!/usr/bin/expect -f

Tags: shell-script

I'm playing overthewire.org/wargames/bandit1.  I got the password readme file from bandit0, but I don't want to type in the 32 character password to access the ssh to bandit 1.  I would like to automate password delivery.

I downloaded the password file and then used nano to add "pass=" to the beginning of the string.  So from that, I can do this:

```
root@system:~/# source /root/Downloads/readme; export pass; echo $pass
<passwordText>
```

Then I wrote this script based on another question asked here
(answer 2 on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928004/how-to-enter-ssh-password-using-bash)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh bandit1@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220 -l bandit1
expect "assword:"
send $pass
interact
```

I then saved and chmod u+x the script file, and then executed. The output says it can't read the variable:

```
password: can't read "pass": no such variable
while executing
"send $pass"
(file "./bandit1" line 4)
```

I know it has something to do with the header, because this script correctly echos the password from variable

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export pass=""
source /root/Downloads/readme
export pass
echo $pass
```

But I'm having trouble finding info on bash script headers this specific.  Can anybody help me clarify this?

Comment: Similar: [Convert password with special characters for use with expect script](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/408974)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pass` as used in the `expect` script is a TCL variable which has nothing whatsoever to do with shell variables or their unfortunate overlap with the strings passed as the environment (see the `environ(7)` man page). In TCL the environment can be accessed via the `env` variable (see the `tclvars(n)` man page). So,

```
$ cat envtest
#!/usr/bin/env expect
puts $env(pass)
set pass $env(pass)
puts $pass
$ chmod +x envtest
$ export pass=Hunter2
$ ./envtest
Hunter2
Hunter2
$
```

Therefore your `expect` code could be written as

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh bandit1@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220 -l bandit1
expect "assword:"
send $env(pass)
interact
```

to directly access the `pass` environment string (well, one of them, anyways, as there's not much stopping duplicate environment variables from being created...)

There's also [a bunch of other ways to handle passwords in `expect`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331519/how-can-i-get-expect-to-ignore-dollar-sign-in-a-password/331520#331520) that don't involve the trouble of the environment (which may be passed on down to child processes and read by them...).