# Expect script embedded in shell: how to specify value defined in remote shell?

Tags: linux, shell, expect

**1. Problem description:**

I have a script which needs to ssh to an remote server and run some scripts.

But I met some troubles when trying to use values that defined in remote server.

I use "\$" to refer to the value defined in remote server but it says the value is not defined...

**2. Error message:**

[image]

**3. Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash  
myusrname="xxx"
myhost="xxx"
mypsword="xxx"

/usr/bin/expect<<-EOF
spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $myusrname@$myhost
expect "*password*"
send "$mypsword\r"
expect "*#*"
send "tst=\"just a test string\"\r"
expect "*#*"
send "echo \$tst\r"
EOF
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: Do you have some particular need for `expect` apart from entering the password? If you just want to pass commands for the remote shell, you can do that without `expect`, and logging in could also be accomplished with ssh keys or something like `sshpass`

Comment: Since you're using unquoted `EOF` (to permit expansion of shell variable `$mypassword`), the shell is "eating" the backslash escape on `\$tst` I think, so that `expect` sees it as an (undefined) expect variable. If you really want to do things this way, try `send "echo \\\$tst\r"`

Comment: @steeldriver you should post that as an answer

Comment: @glennjackman done (though not sure I've explained it clearly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `$tst` to be interpreted by the remote shell, you need to escape it within both `expect` **and** within the local shell, since you're using unquoted EOF to permit expansion of local shell variable `$mypassword`

So try

```
send "echo \\\$tst\r"
```

That way, the here-doc in the local shell will output `\` and `$`, and `expect` will see `\$tst`

Comment: Alternately, use a guoted heredoc

Comment: It works!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a `tst` variable like that. Have a look into [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410544/send-from-variable-in-usr-bin-expect-f).

The command are TCL script and not bash. Try to use the following:

```
set tst "just a test string"
send "echo \$tst\r"
```

You can see the output if you print with `puts`

```
puts $tst
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need to define variable and use it in the remote shell. The value of the variable is based on the data in remote shell...